# Cron expression to fire azure function twice every day

Tags: cron, azure-functions

I have created a Timer trigger azure function which initially was as asked to run just once every day. But now its been asked to twice every day.

So I need to run it morning 2:30 and noon 13:15.

I wrote my cron expression like this

0 30,15 2,13 * * *

But my confusion is will it fire 2:15 and 2:30 and 13:15 and 13:30?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the expression you posted will fire at all four times, as you can see in the [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) screenshot below.

The two explicit times you are requiring are not possible using a single cron expression.

[image: Crontab guru screenshot]

Crontab guru is *The quick and simple editor for cron schedule expressions*.

Please be advised it does not take seconds into account, so remove the first element if you want to check something.